# How to prove $X/\partial X \bigwedge Y/\partial Y\approx (X\times Y)/\partial (X \times Y).$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

My question is

Let $(X, a), (Y, b)\in Top_*$ Prove that $$(X, a)/\partial(X, a) \wedge (Y, b)/\partial (Y, b) \approx (X, a)\times (Y, b)/\partial ((X, a) \times (Y, b)),$$ where ''$\wedge$'' is smash product.

Can you explain for me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you give a context for what $A$ and $B$ are?

Comment: Can you explain your notations? I think it will increase the readability of your post. Also I don't understand you have tagged the question with [tag:algebraic-topology], [tag:inner-product-space] and [tag:smooth-manifolds]. Can you explain that to me?

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews. Let $X, Y$ be two topo spaces and $A \subseteq X, B  \subseteq Y,$ and $A, B$ are closed.set

Comment: Edit your question. The answerers are not expected to read the comments to figure out your question. Help people help you.

Comment: The smash product is defined only for spaces with base points, say $(X,a)$ and $(Y,b)$ . and then by $\partial ((X,a) \times (Y,b))$ you presumably mean $X \times \{b\} \cup \{a\} \times Y$. But it is not clear what you mean by  $\partial  A, \partial B$..

Comment: @ Ronnie Brown. I did fix  my question. Can you prove my problem above? Thank you very much!

Comment: It may be that you are asking about manifolds $X$ with boundary $\partial X$ . In that case the titled question now    makes sense. Try it for the case $X= E^m, Y=E^n$, where $\partial X = S^{m-1}$.